# Open task button in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am starting a task process in SharePoint 2013 and it's working fine. All tasks are getting created successfully though in the email sent to the user `"Open Task"` button in the ribbon is `missing`.
While creating a 2010 OOTB approval workflow button do appear! 
Can anyone help me to `create a open task button in SharePoint 2013 workflow task`?